# function pointer typedef - expression must be a modifiable lvalue error

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, pointer-to-member

i've got a typedef for a function pointer and i'm trying create a function pointer and have it point to a member function of the same class:

```
typedef void(Controls::*KeyFunction)(void);

class Controls
{
public:
    void OnKeyDown(Key key);

    // Key Down Functions
    void KeyLeftDown();
    void KeyRightDown();
    void KeyDownDown();
    void KeyUpDown();
private:
    static BOOL KeyEvent(LPARAM keyFunc, WPARAM null, UINT flags);
};

void Controls::OnKeyDown(Key key)
{
    KeyFunction kFunc;
    switch (key)
    {
    case Key::Left:
        kFunc = KeyLeftDown;
        break;
    case Key::Right:
        kFunc = KeyRightDown;
        break;
    case Key::Up:
        kFunc = KeyUpDown;
        break;
    case Key::Down:
        kFunc = KeyDownDown;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
    SendKeyEvent(kFunc, DO_NOT_REMOVE);
}

BOOL Controls::KeyEvent(LPARAM keyFunc, WPARAM null, UINT flags)
{
    KeyFunction func = (KeyFunction)(keyFunc);
    func();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Using the typedef 'KeyFunction' always gives an error of expression must be a modifiable lvalue. However if i just use the defintion itself and skip the typedef it works.. for example:

```
void(Controls::*kFunc)(void);
        switch (key)
        {
        case Key::Left:
            kFunc = KeyLeftDown;
            break;
        }
```

Completely works???
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the proper syntax to obtain a pointer to a member function:

```
kFunc = &Controls::KeyLeftDown;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! turns out it was a really stupid mistake I made in the .h file, i'd put the typedef before the class declaration and didn't notice. Doing a forward declaration fixed that, but your answer helped me figure that out and is correct for the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Oktalist's answer, after trying to create a compilable version of your code there are 2 major issues with your code:

1. To get a member function pointer, the syntax is `&<ClassName>::<FunctionName>`.

> prog.cpp:31:15: error: cannot convert 'Controls::KeyLeftDown' from type 'void (Controls::)()' to type 'KeyFunction {aka void (Controls::*)()}'
>
> ```
>     kFunc = KeyLeftDown;
> ```
>
> prog.cpp:31:18: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Controls::KeyLeftDown' [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
>     kFunc = &KeyLeftDown;
> ```

2. To invoke such a function, you need to bind it to an object: `(this->*func)()`

> prog.cpp:51:10: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'func (...)', e.g. '(... ->* func) (...)'
>
> ```
> func();
>     ^
> ```